# How to set give space to left and right of table section cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello how can I give space around cells like this

[image]

You can see in the in the image that there are space on the left and right side. Please tell me how can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this permanent for all cells, you can use.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: , left: , bottom: , right)
```

in your viewDidLoad() method
just change left and right as you like

Comment: Watch out , if in TableViewControllers Attribute Inspecter -> ScrollView -> Adjust Scroll View insets is unchecked.

Comment: okay i think nothin i had written is good pratice for that , wait for another answer. sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Leading` and `Trailing` of base `View` with the cell `contentView` to '`X`' `pt` so that it will align themselves exactly the UI shown above.

[image]

> To add the Constraint Right Click on `ImageView` and Drag it on to `contentView` *(as per second image)*, select `Leading Space to Container Margin` *(as per third image)*

[image]

[image]